# How to express "decrease not so much" formally?

Tags: expressions

There are two variables A and B. A decreases from 100 to 5 while B decreases from 100 to 80.

I want to say that the degree of drop for B is less than A. What should I say that more formally?

My answer is "B decreased not so much as A." But I suppose that it is not native English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*not so much as* == *less than*

> B decreased less than A did.
>
> B's level of decrease was less than A's.

Comment: For formal English, I think the first line needs "did" at the end: ***B decreased less than A did***. I think the second line is more precise and the better option.